could someone help me calculate these odds?
I belong to a Fraternal Organization. We have a weekly drawing with 54 cards (the deck and 2 Jokers) in numbered envelopes pinned to a corkboard. We have actually drawn 53 of the 54 cards without picking the winner (the Queen of Hearts, I'm sure some of you have seen this before). I need to know the odds against this happening, I have to believe it is much higher than 54-1.

Each card is equally likely to be in any slot, so the probability that the $Q\heartsuit$ is last is $\frac 1{54}$.  In terms of odds, of course, that would be $53:1$.

Which makes it $53-1$, not $54-1$

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

For what it's worth, $~53~$ to $~1~$ is equivalent to $~1~$ out of $~54.$

Let me first rephrase the question to make sure that we are on the same page about the question.
There is a standard deck of 52 cards and 2 jokers making the deck in use 54 cards. There is a single 'goal' card, in this case the Queen of diamonds. 53 of the 54 cards are randomly drawn from the deck (all but one) and you would like to know the probability that the 'goal' card (the Queen of diamonds) was not one of the 53 cards drawn.
This is the same thing as dealing every single card to 54 people, as we think of an imaginary 54th person as one that holds the last remaining card in the deck. Each person is just as likely to get each card and thus the probability is simply $\frac{1}{54}$. As someone else correctly pointed out above, this is the same as saying 53:1.
